# (python) working with a hex literal trying to convert to string, or int, or anything

Tags: python, string, hex, literals

I'm working on an assignment in which we have to simulate a kaminski attack on a dns server we create.  I'm currently trying to generate the falsified dns reponse packet payload.  Using dnslib I'm generating a packet and then pack() the result.  this gives me a hex literal:

'\xcf\x90\x85\x80\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03abc\x03com\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\xc0\x0c\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\x01\x02\x03\x04'

I don't believe this is the correct format for the payload data.  In specific I think I need to ditch all the "\x"'s so my stream will be 
cf 90 85 80 ...

Unfortunately I can't seem to do this.  String manipulation tools don't seem to work on a literal and the usual literal-> string conversion (literal_eval) fails with an error:

```
TypeError: compile() expected string without null bytes
```

Other conversions I've tried (int(packet,0)) fails because part of the literal is text (leading to odd length).

There's probably a very simple solution, any help?

Answer (score 2):

You seem to miss the meaning of '\x' in that context. '\x' is an escape sequence available in [python string literals](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) such that \xhh represents a character with the hex value of *hh*.

Try dumping that string to a file and output its contents as hex:

```
yoni@gaga:~ python -c "file('payload','wb').write('\xcf\x90\x85\x80\x00\x01')"
yoni@gaga:~ hexdump payload 
0000000 cf 90 85 80 00 01                              
0000006
```

I believe that's exactly the behaviour you were looking for, just go ahead and use that string. If, however, for some reason you do want to convert it to a "human readable" hex string, you could use:

```
''.join(['%x' % ord(x) for x in packet])
```

Comment: I think that's answering what I need, thank you.  I'll try it out later tonight and see.